Backing up discovered network printer configuration
I am dealing with some CUPS issues, and in particular I noticed that automatically discovered network printers are configured differently on the first connection and after executing
# systemctl stop cups
# systemctl start cups

Is there a way to "freeze" the configuration on automatically discovered printers, so that the next time they are connected, they behave exactly the same?

I have dealt with an intermittently connected printer (and appearing/vanishing CUPS print queues and configuration) by setting up a new print queue pointing to the printer, and configuring it the way I want. Visit http://localhost:631.

Following the suggestion here, I did as follows:

I copied the wanted PPD file from /etc/cups/ppd elsewhere under the name printer.ppd.

I disconnected network printers to be sure there is no conflicting generated PPD file in /etc/cups/ppd.

I executed
# lpadmin -p new-printer -P printer.ppd -v ipp://<ip-address>/ipp/print -E

where <ip-address> is the actual IP address.


This created a new printer with the saved configuration called new-printer.
